# apply script to each case element with class "required"

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

if ( $(".required").is(":visible") && $('.required').val() == '') {
event.preventDefault();
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      $('#myModal').hide();
    }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
$('#myModal').dialog('close');
}

});
```

Currently this is only applying to the the first element with class "required", I would like to apply it to each element with class "required"

I tried changing adding .each function to different places in the script but cannot figure it out.

Comment: What do you want to do with `.required`? Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Nm, literally just figured it out.

Comment: $(".required").each(function() {
 if ( $(this).is(":visible") && $(this).val() == '') {
  event.preventDefault();
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

if there are many elements with the class `required`, for example `$('.required').val()` will output only the value of the first occurance

to check each you may use jquerys each function  sth like:

```
$(".required").each(function(i,el){
  if ( $(el).is(":visible") && $(el).val() == '') {
     //....
  }
})
```

Comment: beat me to it :P